# Azure Front Door in the front of Application Gateway Ingress Controller

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I deployed an AKS with Application Gateway Ingress Controller(AGIC) and mapped my custom domain to it and it worked fine.

Now I want to add the Azure Front Door Classic in front of the Application Gateway but it throws this error:

> Our services aren't available right now
> We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

I already created the CNAME record. The AGIC is still working fine with this command:  `curl https://example.com --resolve 'example.com:443:<My-IP-Address>'`

I think the reason is from my Front Door Configuration. But it is very clear and straight forward: 1 domain is my custom domain with cert from Key Vaults, 1 backend pool is my AGIC and a default rule to accept https traffic and forward to backend pool.

Some threads said it is because of the probe. The default probe is / with GET method but didn't work. I temporarily disabled it but no luck either. My curl command above return 200 so the probe is not problem I think

Any clue or docs to show me debug one by one? Cause I don't have any error or logs right now

Answer (score 0):

FrontDoor **and** AppGW is not a common pattern. This is because the most common reason to use both of these services (independently) is to secure ingress traffic with a Public IP address and WAF capability.

Could you not just use Application Gateway as the main ingress point? Is FrontDoor delivering value in the architecure?

If FrontDoor is preferred (and i think we'll see FrontDoor taking over from Application Gateway in many of the Microsoft reference implementations) then can i ask if having AGIC as your Ingress Controller is the best choice? I'd personally want to choose an in-cluster ingress controller if i wasn't getting any broader feature benefit from AppGW.
Paolo has written a comprehensive guide for this here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/how-to-expose-nginx-ingress-controller-via-azure-front-door-and/ba-p/3767535

Comment: Hmm, my use case here is using AGIC for my cluster, it was working fine until I have to add some routes to other Azure services outside of the cluster. So I think implement FrontDoor in front of my AGIC can handover it.